# Create new dataframe column and generate values depending on the previous rows value of this same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a loop to add new columns to a dataframe.
each time it adds a new column , I want to generate the values in the column using lambda function.
The function I wish to pass in the lambda is the function calcOnOff(). This function has 4 parameters :
v3proba, is the value of another column of this same row
on_to_off, is the current val of the loop iterator
off_to_on, is the current val of the second loop iterator
prevOnOff, is the value of this same column on the previous row.

Here is my code below

```
import pandas as pd

# I create a simple dataframe
dataExample={'Name':['Karan','Rohit','Sahil','Aryan','dex'],'v3proba':[0.23,0.42,0.51,0.4,0.7]}
dfExample=pd.DataFrame(dataExample)



# func to be applied on each new column of the dataframe
def calcOnOff(v3proba, on_to_off, off_to_on, prevOnOff):
    if(prevOnOff == "OFF" and (v3proba*100) >= off_to_on ):
        return "ON"
    elif(prevOnOff == "OFF" and (v3proba*100) < off_to_on ):
        return "OFF"
    elif(prevOnOff == "ON" and (v3proba*100) < on_to_off ):
        return "OFF"
    elif(prevOnOff == "ON" and (v3proba*100) >= on_to_off ):
        return "ON"
    else:
        return "ERROR"


# my iterators
off_to_on = 50 
on_to_off = 49 

# loops to generate new columns and populate col values
for off_to_on in range(50,90):
    for on_to_off in range(10,49):
        dfExample[str(off_to_on) + '-' + str(on_to_off)] = dfExample.apply(lambda row: calcOnOff(row['v3proba'], on_to_off, off_to_on, row[str(off_to_on) + '-' + str(on_to_off)].shift()), axis=1)

    
dfExample
```

The expected output would be a table with arround 1500 columns that look like this :

[image]

I think  the problem in my algo is how to handle the first row as .shift() will look for an inexistant row?

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: For the case `Rohit, v3proba=0.42` you show that `50-42: ON`. Why?

Comment: You have pointed out a typo/mistake, it is supposed to be OFF.
The answer you have submitted seems to work although my novice level of python does not let me understand each line of your code.
Would it have been achievable with a .apply lambda approach?

Comment: @JK2018 Yes, we can do it with `global`, for example. See updated answer, Post Script area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preliminary remarks

1. You can't address the field before it's created. So the code `row[f'{off_to_on}-{on_to_off}'].shift()` won't work, you'll get a `KeyError` here.
2. I guess, you want to shift down one row along the column by expression `row[...].shift()`. It doesn't work like that. `row[...]` returns a value, which is contained in a cell, not the column.
3. It's not clear what should be the *previous state* for the very *first row*. What is the value of `prevOnOff` parameter in this case?

### How to fill in the column taking into account previous calculations

Let's use generators for this purpose. They can keep the inner state, so we can reuse a previously calculated value to get the next one.

But first, I'm gonna clarify the logic of `calcOnOff`. As I can see, it returns `On` if `proba >= threshold` or `Off` otherwise, where `threshold` is `on_off` if `previous == On` or `off_on` otherwise. So we can rewrite it like this:

```
def calcOnOff(proba, on_off, off_on, previous):
    threshold = on_off if previous == 'On' else off_on
    return 'On' if proba >= threshold else 'Off'
```

Next, let's transform `previous` to boolean and `calcOnOff` into a generator:

```
def calc_on_off(on_off, off_on, prev='Off'):
    prev = prev == 'On'
    proba = yield
    while True:
        proba = yield 'On' if (prev:=proba >= (on_off if prev else off_on)) else 'Off'
```

Here I made an assumption that the initial state is `Off` (default value of `prev`), and assume that previous value was `On` if `prev == True` or `Off` otherwise.

Now, I suggest to use `itertools.product` in order to generate parameters `on_off` and `off_on`. For each pair of these values we create an individual generator:

```
calc = calc_on_off(on_off, off_on).send
calc(None)    # push calc to the first yield
```

This we can apply to the `100 * df['v3proba']`:

```
proba = 100*df['v3proba']
df[...] = proba.apply(calc)
```

### Full code

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

data = {
    'Name': ['Karan','Rohit','Sahil','Aryan','dex'],
    'v3proba': [0.23,0.42,0.51,0.4,0.7]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


def calc_on_off(on_off, off_on, prev='Off'):
    prev = prev == 'On'
    proba = yield
    while True:
        prev = proba >= (on_off if prev else off_on)
        proba = yield 'On' if prev else 'Off'


proba = 100*df.v3proba
on_off = range(10, 50)
off_on = range(50, 90)

for state in product(on_off, off_on):
    calc = calc_on_off(*state).send
    calc(None)
    name = '{1}-{0}'.format(*state)   # 0:on_off, 1:off_on
    df[name] = proba.apply(calc)
```

### Update: Comparing with the provided expected result

[image]

---

### P.S. No Generators

What if I don't want to use generators? Then we have somehow keep intermediate output outside the function. Let's do it with globals:

```
def calc_on_off(proba):
    # get data outside
    global prev, on_off, off_on
    threshold = on_off if (prev == 'On') else off_on
    # save data outside
    prev = 'On' if proba >= threshold else 'Off'
    return prev


default_state = 'Off'
proba = 100*df.v3proba
r_on_off = range(10, 50)
r_off_on = range(50, 90)

for on_off, off_on in product(r_on_off, r_off_on):
    prev = default_state
    df[f'{off_on}-{on_off}'] = proba.apply(calc_on_off)
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. The first way to do it seem to be working fine, but when I try the second method using globals, I get a different output

Comment: @JK2018 You are right. I spotted and fixed the error. See updated function in post script. Let me know if it works now.